# Batch rename files with unknown names and unknown extensions

Tags: rename

I have a bunch of pictures, some are `.jpg`, some are `.png`.  any given picture could have an entirely random name (possibly including spaces).  in any given directory, how can I rename all of them, while keeping the extension as is?  the input, for example:

```
001.jpg
02.png
05.png
zzzz.jpg
```

I would like to completely replace their names with four-digit numbers, starting with `0001`, and going up to `9999` (if necessary). thus, the output might look like:

```
0001.jpg
0002.png
0003.png
0004.jpg
```

the order of these files is important to me, but they are already in sequential order if I were to sort them by filename alone.

I have checked out the perl `rename`, and its usage is a mystery to me in this example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Perl Solution**

```
perl -e '
    @files = sort glob "*.png *.jpg";
    for(@files){ 
        ($extension = $_) =~ s/.*\.(.*)/$1/;
        $new_name = sprintf("%04d",++$counter).".$extension";
        die "File $new_name already exists and would be clobbered\n" if -e $new_name;
        rename $_ => sprintf("%04d",++$counter).".$extension"
     }'
```

**Bash Solution**

```
export COUNT=0 
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.png" -print0 | xargs -0 sort | while read file do\
extension=${file##*.}\
COUNT=$((COUNT+1))\
mv -- "$file" $(printf "%04d" $COUNT).$extension\
done
```

**Note**

- <s>Both solutions are</s> Bash solution is untested: try <s>them</s> it on dummy files first.
- The Bash solution may break if you have file names with newlines in them.
- **Danger:** As pointed out by Gilles in the comments below, if one of the original files has a name that follows the target naming convention, it will at best be renamed to another "number" and at worst be clobbered by another file. Which one happens will depend on how it sorts relative to other files. I have added a provision for this in the Perl solution since this is the one the OP seems to favor.
- The Perl solution (with the provision from the above point implemented) is [non-idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence).

Comment: You need to use `%04d` in printf for padding, otherwise it gets space-padded toward the right (and the spaces subsequently ignored).

Comment: I definitely like the Perl solution better, myself; it should be safe even in the face of weird file names. I'm not sure but I get the feeling that the bash solution centered around `while read` is still vulnerable to IFS issues.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Do you happen to have an edge case in mind?

Comment: Not a likely one in the OP's case, but at least a possible one in the general case. Newlines in file names have been known to trip up more than one script like this (and I'm probably guilty of the same kind of things myself...).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Interesting. Perhaps we can add this as a caution to the Bash solution.

Comment: Since in the Perl solution you're putting the file names into an array which you then iterate over, that one should be safe as long as `glob` does its job properly.

Comment: @JosephR. the perl solution *almost* works, the only problem being the extension gets erased.

Comment: @azaqiel Typo fixed in answer (added extra slash at the end of the regex). Try now.

Comment: didn't work. I'm no pro, but my thoughts are A) ignore three characters on the right (which in this case are always the extension) inside the regex, or B) use a regex that only operates until a period.

Comment: @azaqiel Tested on my box and found the source of the problem: missing punctuation. Should work fine now.

Comment: Warning: if any of the source files matches the target pattern, it may get erased in the process.

Comment: @Gilles Great point. Adding to answer.

Comment: @azaqiel Please check out the updated answer.

Comment: Why not to add a conditional check [[ -e $newfilename ]] before doing the actual move to overcome the possibility of clobbering the file? And if this condition happens, the counter should be incremented and new filename assigned ...

Comment: @Bichoy Because this can potentially mess up the sorting order required by the OP. If he/she has a file called `0009.png` for example, that is supposed to be sorted as the 45th file, he will have files named `000{1..8}.png`, `0010.png` and so on and the file `0009.png` that was originally supposed to become `0045.png` will become `0046.png`

Comment: Tried to copy/paste the bash solution into my terminal, just get the greater-than sign indicating it isn't a complete command... rusty on bash, don't see why...?

Answer (score 1):

(`bash` solution)

Using `printf` to format the new names and `awk` to pick out the filename extension...

```
$ ls
a.b  c.d  e.f  g.h  i.j  k.l  m.n  o.p  q.r  s.t  this file.y  u.v  w.x
$ COUNTER=0
$ for i in *; do COUNTER=$(($COUNTER + 1)); mv -v "$i" $(printf "%04g" $COUNTER).$(echo $i | awk -F'.' '{print $NF}'); done
`a.b' -> `0001.b'
`c.d' -> `0002.d'
`e.f' -> `0003.f'
`g.h' -> `0004.h'
`i.j' -> `0005.j'
`k.l' -> `0006.l'
`m.n' -> `0007.n'
`o.p' -> `0008.p'
`q.r' -> `0009.r'
`s.t' -> `0010.t'
`this file.y' -> `0011.y'
`u.v' -> `0012.v'
`w.x' -> `0013.x'
```

Remember to surround the input `$i` in quotes to escape spaces in filenames, as you have mentioned.

Comment: Nice, but you could replace the `$(echo $i | awk -F'.' '{print $NF}')` with `${i##*.}` and keep the whole thing bash (since `printf` is a builtin IIRC). Also, you should either use `mv --` or prepend a `./` to the glob to avoid problems with files starting with a `-`.

Comment: Warning: if any of the source files matches the target pattern, it may get erased in the process.

Comment: @evilsoup valid point, however: h.j.k.'s original version with `echo` and `awk` would also work on older and real old `bash` versions, considering that a statement like `${i##*.}`, though very elegant, was still on the users' wishlist in `bash` 2.x times (if I remember correctly).

Answer (score -1):

Save this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

NUM=0
NUMBER_LENGTH=4

cd $1;

ls . -1 | sort | while read file; do
    NUM=$(( $NUM + 1 ));
    PREFIX=$NUM;
    while [ ${#PREFIX} != $NUMBER_LENGTH ]; do
        PREFIX="0${PREFIX}";
    done;
    NEW_NAME=$PREFIX.`echo $file | sed 's|[^.]\+\.\([\A-Za-z0-9]\+\)|\1|g'`;
    mv "$file" "$NEW_NAME";
done
```

and execute it as:

```
./_scriptname_ _dirWhereYourStuffIs_
```

CAVEAT: don't put the script in the same dir where your stuff is, because the script itself would be renamed.

If you're insane enough, you can do it all in a line (without using the script):

```
NUM=0; NUMBER_LENGTH=4; ls . -1 | sort | while read file; do NUM=$(( $NUM + 1 )); PREFIX=$NUM; while [ ${#PREFIX} != $NUMBER_LENGTH ]; do PREFIX="0${PREFIX}"; done; NEW_NAME=$PREFIX.`echo $file | sed 's|[^.]\+\.\([\A-Za-z0-9]\+\)|\1|g'`; mv "$file" "$NEW_NAME"; done
```

CAVEAT #2: for this single line, I'm assuming you're using BASH

Comment: Generally, [don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). And you can replace your inner `while` loop with `PREFIX=$(printf '%04d' $NUM)`.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Though I agree with you that parsing `ls` is an __epic fail__, I have to state that the perfect, OS-independent line is one that new users will not always be able to think of so easily: `while read file; do (...); done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f)` -- the greatest difficulty of which is the "reverse thinking" that the `find` output must be somewhat "post-injected" at the very __end__ of the loop. I didn't find it too logical either when I was a beginner in this TBH.

Comment: @syntaxerror I believe `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | while read file; do (...); done` works just as well, and is more intuitive. I used a script for a good while that used exactly that construct (actually, with a `sort` thrown in for good measure); it was eventually retired when I rewrote it (ironically, with one loop using just about the exact construct you mention) because I needed the script to do things rather differently compared to what it did, making it easier to rewrite than adapt in place.

Comment: However, parsing the output of `find` does suffer from some of the same problems as parsing the output of `ls`. Since the question title explicitly says **unknown names and extensions** this is potentially a problem. A good solution then will be one that can handle unusual file names as well.

Comment: But I think we can agree that it's not in such an extreme way as `ls`, Michael. *This* is the difference. `ls` output (especially `ls -(a)l` output) may vary __hugely__ due to different locale settings etc, hence the wrongest thing to do is piping `awk` to `ls -l` output (on system #1, field name $12 may correspond to field $15 on system #2). -- Whereas the differences in `find` output seem marginal to me in comparison, if existing at all.